# CSS - How to float correctly into pseudocolumns

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

Please see the image below. Assume that these are all divs with the given ids. Also, let's assume that they carry the same weight semantically so they should be at the same point in the html hierarchy:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

What is the proper CSS to position them correctly so as to appear as in the image below? The solution should flow properly as the browser is resized and preferably work on >=IE7.

[image: Div element positioning]

Think of this as an action panel (#1) and 3 information displays (#2, #3, #4) so it is probably expected for 2,3,4 to expand in width to fill the browser window and flow below the action panel as the browser shrinks.

Comment: @Jakub - Only for #1, see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4{ float:left; }
#id1{ width:50%; height:300px; background-color:red; }
#id2{ width:50%; height:50px; background-color:blue; }
#id3{ width:25%; height:250px; background-color:green; }
#id4{ width:25%; height:250px; background-color:yellow; }
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wsEt6/

---

I altered your `id`s as they are not allowed to be numeric.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

Comment: So its all a matter of explicitly setting heights and widths? Far easier than I thought.

Comment: @George, yes - for a completely fluid set-up. Although this will not work for the updated question where you want `#id1` to be fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I just read the bottom piece, so my example is fixed (width)...

An `id` can't be a number, but to keep your example I'll use the numbers spelled out.

CSS:

```
.container { overflow:hidden; /* Clear Floats */ width:400px; }
#one, #two, #three, #four { float:left; }
#one { width:200px; }
#two { width:200px; }
#three { width:100px; }
#four { width:100px; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DOSBeats/CqSTY/

Comment: good, but 2,3 and 4 don't expand according to viewport width. I was about to upvote you when I noticed this requirement by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use container divs for those. Something like this:

```
<div id="one" class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the best get-it-done way but that's a cheat, it puts 2,3,4 at a different semantic level than 1. Worse, it won't work properly in all set-ups. Say #2 is half its length, then as the browser window is scaled horizontally, #4 should flow beneath #1 while #2 and #3 remain in place

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `#1, #2, #3, #4` in a container div, `#0.5`. Float the `#1` div left and have a width of `50%`. Wrap `#1, #2, #3` in a container div named, `#container` - float that right with a width of `50%`.

Do the same thing for the divs inside `#container`

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps you out just remember to modify divs as you need it all in the div play with them according to the screen size you need :

http://jsfiddle.net/z747R/